# I have to upgrade my application python version from 2 to python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have to upgrade my application's python version from 2 to python 3.

how i can check all python 2 library dependencies. Whether it will break any libs dependencies in python 3.

any suggestion over this will be appreciated.

Currently checking with -

Python2to3- Code fixer used to correct language syntax and annotator.

Pip check - collects all libs and its version dependency.(Not working for me in server)

CanIusepython3- Python module.

pipdeptree - But how it will tell me whether package version compatible with python3 or not.

Comment: You run your tests using Python 3 instead of (or in addition to) Python 2; something like [`tox`](https://pypi.org/project/tox/) may help.

Comment: Thank you Chepner i will try this tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this library:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

If it does not do a well good of a job, you can always try manualy. It's an incremental process so you would need to change things slowly.

Comment: Thanks you Nikola for your suggestion.
i have used this library as code fixer and resolved almost all syntax and annotator from code.
But this lib did not help me to find any lib dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

### Used modules

An automated tool can probably not give you complete information, for several reasons;

- Some modules have changed name or usage between Python 2 and Python3 compatible versions.
- Some modules might not have been updated for Python 3, but alternatives exist.

So I would suggest the following. Using e.g. `egrep`, extract all the `import` statements from the applications code. I would use something like this (from the source code directory):

```
egrep -Rh '^import .+|^from [^\.].+ import' . | sort | uniq
```

If your operating system doesn't support these tools, you can easily write a small python script to extract import statements from all your code files.

Once you have a listing of all imports, disregard modules that are part of the standard library or that are part of the application.

For the remaining external modules you will have to search online and check if there is a Python 3 compatible version or alternative.

### Converting your code

As mentioned, `2to3` can do most of the changes that can be automated for you.

For the rest I would recommend using a good code checker like e.g. `pylama` and an automatic code re-formatter like e.g. `yapf`.

Comment: Thank you Roland for your valuable inputs.